# Doctrine: Only load ID of relationship

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, relationship

Is it possible with Doctrine to say that I only want to get the ID of an relationship (n:1) loaded?
The ID itself is a natural value and in most times I don't need the related entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the association as lazy. It should not load the object, just a proxy. Object will be initialized immediately after any method is called, **except the call for the ID**.

This is the syntax – http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytoone.

Example of "getId" method in the generated proxy class:

```
public function getId()
{
    if ($this->__isInitialized__ === false) {
        return (int) $this->_identifier["id"];
    }
    $this->__load();
    return parent::getId();
}
```

As you see the record won't be loaded if the proxy is not initialized.

Comment: How does Doctrine know which method is for getting the ID?

Comment: The method should be named "get<IdColumnName>".

Comment: Is it really the column name or the name of the attribute in the class?

Comment: Ok, I tested it and it actually is not the column name but the name of the attribute in the class. For example I have a class `Image` with primary key `image_id` and the ID-attribute is named `imageID`. When I named the method `getImage_id()` it doesn't work but when I called it `getImageID()` instead it worked perfectly. But in the case they are named the same it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's class parameter name.